# What Mac to start

Tags: iphone, ipad, mac, mac-mini, developer-program

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Mac to develop iPhone apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7495/which-mac-to-develop-iphone-apps)

I am new to this. I am looking to get into Mac, iPhone and iPad app development. I just enrolled in the dev program. It would be appreciated if you could please let me know what low cost Mac desktop or laptop config needed to start that can keep up with current OS types in the devices and use the cloud?

I have been looking for second hand machines on eBay, but not sure which one to bid on. Can you help?

Kind regards
Max

Comment: duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7495/which-mac-to-develop-iphone-apps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469/whats-a-good-machine-for-iphone-development

Answer (score 1):

Mac Mini is the best option. Get one with 2gb+ Ram and at least a Dual Core 2 Duo.

Then all you need is Xcode

Comment: I would suggest more memory as per the earlier question.

Comment: those are the specs needed to develop with iOS and iClould, just as the question asked, the OP is looking for low cost, hence why they are using eBay. If more money is available I would advise not buying second hand or from eBay.

Comment: Core 2 Duo will be fine. I would highly suggest buying some extra ram. 2gb i dont think is enough. Ram is cheap. You could also upgrade after you have bought if needed.